# C - Assignment makes integer from pointer without a cast

Tags: c

I'm getting this error: 
Warning: assignment makes integer from pointer without a cast [enabled by default]
This is my source code:

```
int     ft_replace(char const *s1)
{
    int     result;

    result = 0;
    for (; *s1 != '\0'; ++s1)
    {
        if (*s1 == '-')
            result = s1; // Warning here
    }

    return (result);
}
```

So, I'm getting an error ( warning ) and my result of my function ft_replace is fxc... 
It return me a result like 4227111 and I don't know why
 I would like my function when it find the last char here this is ' - ' it return the position of the array.

So a string which contains " Hel-l-o " -> Return 6 
A string which contains    " He-llo  " -> Return 3 
A string which contains    " Hell-o- " -> Return 7

Comment: Well.. it's pretty clearly said - `s1` is pointer, not a number(index). You can use additional counter, to count the index/position, or use pointer arithmetic to calculate the position.

Comment: @user3208656 And what to return if the character is not found in a string?

Comment: What is the intent of this function? Are you trying to return the index of the last '-' within s1? If so then you probably want this instead: `int     ft_replace(char const *s1)
{
    int     result;

    result = 0;
    for (const char* s = s1; *s != '\0'; ++s)
    {
        if (*s == '-')
            result = (s1-s);
    }

    return (result);
}
`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you mean the following

```
int ft_replace( const char *s )
{
    int    pos = -1;
    const char *p = s;

    for ( ; *p != '\0'; ++p )
    {
        if ( *p == '-' ) pos = p - s;
    }

    return pos;
}
```

As for your code then this statement

```
result = s1;
```

does not make sense. In the left side of the assignment there is an object of type `int` while in the right side of the assignment there is a pointer of type `const char *`

If you want to return pointer to the last occurence of character '-' then the function can look like

```
char * ft_replace( const char *s )
{
    char *pos = NULL;

    for ( ; *s != '\0'; ++s )
    {
        if ( *s == '-' ) pos = ( char * )s;
    }

    return pos;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

`result = s1`

`result` is an `int`, integer
`s1` is a `char const*`, a const pointer to char

You can't assign the value of a `const char*` to an `integer` (because they might not have the same size for example).

You can however, as hinted by the warning, *cast* the value to the correct type to force it to stop warning you:

```
result = (int)s1;
          ^ this casts the value of s1 to the int type
```

But this is not a good practice as it can induce undefined behavior.
Reading your code, I don't think you are doing what you think you are doing anyway when you assign `s1` to `result`.
What you *should* be doing, is incrementing a counter and set `result` during the loop:

```
int     ft_replace(char const *s1)
{
  int result;
  int i;

  result = -1;
  i = 0;
  for (; *s1 != '\0'; ++s1)
  {
    i++;
    if (*s1 == '-')
      result = i;
  }

  return (result);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In your code, `result` is `int` and `s1` is `char const *`.

You can change it to

```
 result = *s1;
```

However, there is no way to know the *position* of the array currently. You need to have a separate counter to keep track of the *valid* element present in the *array*.

Comment: @Eregrith: You certainly can assign a `char` to an `int`, it just won't do anything useful in this case.

Comment: @Eregrith what about §6.5.16.1, paragraph 2?

Comment: @KirilKirov well, OP has logical issue in his code, that I have pointed out later. Otherwise, as per the question title, this is the way to remove the error. Now whether if fits the logic, that is another aspect (which also I addressed, I think).

Comment: @BillLynch And NatashaDutta you are both right. My bad

Comment: @Natasha Dutta How do you do?:)

Comment: @NatashaDutta as per the title and the warning itself the way to remove it without changing behaviour is by casting rather than by dereferencing

Comment: @Eregrith I'm afraid, you're wrong. casting is never a good solution in _most_ of the cases, specifically pointer-to-int casts and vice versa.

Comment: @Eregrith and in that way (casting), to remove the warning, you'll introduce the high-possibility of UB.

Answer (score 0):

A pointer holds the memory address, not the position in the array.

Use an index variable to keep track of the position.

Note that the first element in an array in C has index `0`, hence the `+1` when assigning `result`:

```
int     ft_replace(char const *s1)
{
    int     result, i;

    result = 0; 
    for (i = 0; s1[i] != '\0'; ++i)
    {
        if (s1[i] == '-')
            result = i + 1;
    }

    return (result);
}
```